# Find and Copy files with wildcard in filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a big folder of files and I would like to find and copy specific files. There are no subfolders - all files are in the same path.

The problem is - a part of the file is always different and it is impossible to guess, so using the wildcard is required.

Here's a script:

```
dir K:\ALL_FILES /s/b|for /f %%i in ('find "First File To Copy.*.jpg"') do copy "%%i" k:\COPIED_FILES
dir K:\ALL_FILES /s/b|for /f %%i in ('find "Second File to be copied.*.jpg"') do copy "%%i" k:\COPIED_FILES
```

The above script works if I replace * with the real part of the file name.

I would like to do it in a batch file, but may be it would be easier to do with Powershell?

Comment: `find` doesn't take wildcards. `for /r "K:\ALL_FILES" %%i in ("first file to copy.*.jpg") do...` might be what you want.

Comment: Also, what about ```@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "K:\ALL_FILES\First File To Copy.*.jpg" /A:-D /B /S 2^>NUL') Do @Copy "%%G" "K:\COPIED_FILES"```

Comment: Do the filenames have anything in common (except for the extension) ?

Comment: Time to use powershell like one of your tags says.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, it worked great and quite quick on a very big directory of files.

Comment: Are all your files in the folder `K:\ALLFILES` or are there subfolders to be searched ? `"...big folder of files..."` implies all files in a single folder, but the `/s` parameter in the `dir` commands imply otherwise. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, they are all in the same folder, the /s parameter was set if I decided to make some maintenance ;) Edited the question as you requested.

Comment: when no subdirectories are to be processed, just: `for %%i in ("first file to copy.*.jpg") do...` or for two files `for %%i in ("first file to copy.*.jpg" "Second File to be copied.*.jpg") do...` with a `cd /d "K:\ALL_FILES" before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that all your files are in a single folder makes this task easier, since most **PowerShell** cmdlets that take a `-Path` parameter accept string *arrays* for the parameter. So if you execute the cmdlet from the directory containing your files, the `-Path` array can contain your wildcard match patterns. This allows all the filtering to be done by the [FileSystem Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers), which is faster than using `-Include` or `-Exclude` parameters or piping files to `Where-Object`.

```
$SourceDir     = 'k:\ALLFILES`
$DestDir       = 'k:\COPIED_FILES'
$MatchPatterns = @('First File To Copy.*.jpg','Second File To Copy.*.jpg')

Set-Location $SourceDir
Copy-Item -Path $MatchPattterns -Destination $DestDir
```

If you're just working interactively at the console, you can reduce the typing burden using aliases, positional parameters, and literal parameter values:

```
$MatchPatterns = @('First File To Copy.*.jpg','Second File To Copy.*.jpg')

sl k:\ALLFILES
copy $MatchPattterns k:\COPIED_FILES
```

And if you have a larger set of match patterns, a multiline [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) makes for easier creation/editing:

```
$MatchPatterns = @'
First File To Copy.*.jpg
Second File To Copy.*.jpg
...
Tenth File to Copy.*.jpg
' -split "`n"
```

Documentation:

- [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.3)

---

---

### Files in Subfilders: Recursive copy vs. Recursive file selection

While `Copy-Item` has the option of a `-Recurse` parameter, it doesn't recurse the file selection criteria through subfolders, instead, when the target of the copy command is a directory, it controls whether or not the *contents* of the directory is copied along with the folder itself.

If you want to select files from a folder and its subfolders, you want to *select* the files using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with the `-Recurse` parameter, and then pipe the selected files for whatever further processing you choose, be it copy, move, or whatever. A simple example, selecting all text files in a folder and its subfolders, would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\FolderPath' -Filter *.txt -Recurse
```

And while the options available to Get-ChildItem are sufficient for some scenarios, multiple criteria or matching more precise than wildcards require more advanced filtering. For those situations, you pipe the output of Get-ChildItem to [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) -- the "Swiss Army Knife" of object filtering in **PowerShell**. It can use any of the [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) available in **PowerShell** to test the properties of an object, or evaluate any script block that returns a boolean.

So, if your example contained subfolders with files you wanted to copy, you could use: (filename match patterns simplified for readability)

```
$SourceDir     = 'k:\ALLFILES`
$DestDir       = 'k:\COPIED_FILES'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter *.jpg -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.Name -like 'ABC.*.jpg') -or ($_.Name -like 'DEF.*.jpg')} |
Copy-Item -Destination $DestDir
```

And while the above `Where-Object` scriptblock does the trick for matching two different patterns, it could quickly become cumbersome for more than a few patterns. Using a regular expression for matching is more concise and more efficient. A regex comparison version of the above would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter *.jpg -Recurse |
    Where-Object Name -match '(ABC|DEF)\..*\.jpg' |
Copy-Item -Destination $DestDir
```

You can see that the regex could be easily expanded to include more literal prefixes before becoming unwieldy. And of course, an even lengthier regex could be assigned to a string variable prior to the operation and the variable used in the operation itself.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. Now what should I do if all those files in K:\ALL_FILES folder were scattered in different subfolders? Would it be a complete different approach?

Comment: @Koles:  the given link tells you about `-Recurse`, including examples of how to use it.

Comment: @KolesGit: I've edited my answer to discuss recursion and provide examples. Hope that helps. Study the online documentation as well, and play with `Get-ChildItem`, `Where-Object`, and their various parameters to familiarize yourself.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you, I put every information from replies/solutions to my archive to analyze it once I get more familiar with PS. Thanks to the help of people like you, I could create a script with over 260 lines (an advanced user would make it within 30, I'm sure). This script was dealing with only one file at a time and due to usage of lots of variables, I had no idea how to make it for all 1000s files in the directory. Do you know what I did? I created another script with Get-ChildItem and passed all filenames as a  parameter, launching the main script 1000 times. (continued..)

Comment: @KeithMiller This one simple script has saved me so much time, if I had to do it manually, it would take years. Being at the beginning of my PS journey, I realized how powerful Powershell is, and although I wanted first to learn Python, now I decided to take time and give PS a chance. From what I see, understanding nesting and looping (multiple ForEach-Object for example) is going to be most crucial to be able to make Powershell my friend. Thanks again for taking the time to share your knowledge.

Comment: @KolesGit: You're welcome. Always happy to help and even happier to turn someone on to **PowerShell**. I never did much with `.bat` coding, `.vbs` was better  suited to my automation needs in the XP days. I was comfortable with that and, like so many others, on first glance at **PowerShell**, saw only an overly-verbose Command Prompt -- and thus ignored it for years. When I finally dove into **PowerShell** and realized its power and flexibility, I was hooked. It's also a great way to become acquainted with the `.NET` framework and `C#` syntax (`Add-Type` definitions) in bite-sized doses!